# Snipcart data-item-url not working on localhost

Tags: html, snipcart

I'm currently testing product payment on local (Wampserver) but I always have a 'domain-crawling-failed' error I can't solve when it comes to confirm payment.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVxjd.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iU0zJ.png

I've set 'localhost' as default domain on snipcart and also put sub-domains :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhouQ.png

My products with the buy-button are in the page:"http://localhost/Site/boutique". Here is the code :

```
<ul id="Product-List">
    <li class="product-item shown">
        <img src="assets/word.png">
        <div class="product-description">
            <h1>Word Guide Complet</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="product-pay">
            <h2>39,99 €</h2>
            <button class="buy-button snipcart-add-item"
            data-item-id="word"
            data-item-price="39.99"
            data-item-url="http://localhost/Site/boutique"
            data-item-description="Le guide complet de Word"
            data-item-image="assets/word.png"
            data-item-name="Word Guide Complet">
                Ajouter au panier
            </button>
        </div>
       
    </li>
    <li class="product-item shown">
        <img src="assets/excel.png">
        <div class="product-description">
            <h1>Excel Guide Complet</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="product-pay">
            <h2>39,99 €</h2>
            <button class="buy-button snipcart-add-item"
            data-item-id="excel"
            data-item-price="39.99"
            data-item-url="http://localhost/Site/boutique"
            data-item-description="Le guide complet de Excel"
            data-item-image="assets/excel.png"
            data-item-name="Excel Guide Complet">
                Ajouter au panier
            </button>
        </div>
        
    </li>
    <li class="product-item shown">
        <img src="assets/powerpoint.png">
        <div class="product-description">
            <h1>Powerpoint Guide Complet</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="product-pay">
            <h2>39,99 €</h2>
            <button class="buy-button snipcart-add-item"
            data-item-id="powerpoint"
            data-item-price="39.99"
            data-item-url="http://localhost/Site/boutique"
            data-item-description="Le guide complet de Powerpoint"
            data-item-image="assets/powerpoint.png"
            data-item-name="Powerpoint Guide Complet">
                Ajouter au panier
            </button>
        </div>
        
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Understanding how the order validation works helps a lot to figure out potential solutions to this, explanation here: https://docs.snipcart.com/v3/setup/order-validation The main culprit here is that the URL that is requested for validation by snipcart, either by prepending the default domain to the relative URL or taking the absolute URL in `data-item-url`, needs to be publicly accessible. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77813346/snipcart-url-of-some-products-could-not-be-reached-when-test-ordering-on-webs/77813347#77813347 for other solutions for a similar problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Snipcart` needs to validate the product price, and to do that it will try to access the `data-item-url` and try to validate the product price there.

But, the Snipcart can not access your `localhost`. You have to put the validator data somewhere where the `Snipcart` can access it. You can do this in several ways:

**SOLUTION 1**

For example, you can create an project on `codesandbox.io` (or any other online editor). In that project, create one `json` file and put all the products `ids` and `prices` inside. Now you can set the value of `data-item-url` to point on that `json`. Since `codesandbox.io` project is on the cloud, `Snipcart` will be able to access it and validate the product price. Downside of this solution is that you will need to modify manually this `json` whenever you have the new product or you change the price of existing product.

NOTE: Remember to add `codesandox.io` domain to `Snipcart's` Domains and Subdomains in `Snipcart` Dashboard.

Example of `json` file in `codesandbox` project:

```
https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-sid-6jqpl?file=/src/assets/all-products.json
```

**SOLUTION 2**

You can use the `ngrok` npm package to tunnel the data to your `localhost`. That way `Snipcart` will be able to validate the products even in your `localhost`. Downside of this solution is that you need to create `ngrok` account to be able to use the package.

`ngrok` package:

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngrok
```

**SOLUTION 3**

This is the best solution if you ask me. Create an endpoint on your server that will return all the products from your database in a `json` document. When you do that, you can set `data-item-url` to point on that `endpoint` on your server. Whenever the `Snipcart` needs to validate something it will call your server, and your server will always return up-to-date data. All you need to do now is to host your server somewhere in the cloud so `Snipcart` can access that endpoint.

NOTE: Remember to add your server domain to `Snipcart's` Domains and Subdomains in `Snipcart` Dashboard.

Comment: Your third solutions seems to be what I'm looking for but as I'm kinda new to web development I don't really know how to create that endpoint on my wampserver and return my products to a json file. If you have a tutorial that could help me about it would be really appreciated

Comment: Nvm actually I used ngrok and I succeeded to make it work, ty for your help !

Comment: I am glad to hear that. About the third solution and creating the endpoint, what is the technology that you are using on server side? Also, consider upvoting my answer if it helped you.

Comment: I'm running a php website on wampserver (I can't upvote I just created my account so I don't even have 15 reputation)

Comment: I don't know how API endpoint can be created in PHP. I am JavaScript developer. Maybe you can check some youtube tutorial or some course on https://www.coursera.org/

Comment: @KenTay7 Hosting the json file on your local wampserver would not solve the issue by the way. It would need to be hosted on some publicly accessible domain. That is the underlying issue.